# Copy attachment from one task to another

Tags: attachment, asana

I need to copy attachment from a task and it should be pasted to another task. How it can be done?

Basically I am implementing "Copy Project" manually, so I need to copy all attachments related task too.

Answer (score 0):

Oof. There is no way to clone directly, so you'd need to download the attachment and upload it again. Potentially very slow :-(